# Changing the query in oracle apps for quotation

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad, formbuilder

when the HSN code is not available for particular item code  so the user should not able to see  the ok button after approving. So accordingly to that ....we have to change the function and query in the oracle apps using form builder and TOAD and after all we have to test it whether the button is still available.

Result: the OK BUTTON should not be available for the users who is not having HSN code for its item code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create flag for visible or not visible, after that you do select your table, and change visible object.